# Can't make a map in Minecraft 0.14.2

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm just having some trouble with Minecraft PE. I cannot seem to be able to make a map. I select a blank map in my inventory and tap "Create Map", but it doesn't seem to do anything. I have no idea what is going on. I'm using a Moto G 3rd Generation. Any help would be welcome, thanks :)

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Nope, there's a kind of animation but it just moves the item in my hand and nothing else.

Comment: Sorry xD and all that happens is my hand moves, like when placing or destroying blocks. However, nothing happens.

Comment: I don't think you understood properly. My phone runs the game and the worlds fine, it's the map ITEM in the inventory that doesn't work.

Comment: Okay, okay, maybe it's a bug or something else.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. Thanks for the help anyway :) much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're in Creative Mode. The map won't replace the Map in the hotbar with the Map that you made. It will be put it in your inventory. Simply open it up and take your map and put it on the hotbar. It should work.